# Loading all titles from database and show them in a popup Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

How i can select just a day that include an event and can't be able to select others days, which i can a get  a pop up including all the titles in my database i'm searching a lot but i don't found the solution any help

Comment: Select all events, then foreach it with saving days.

Comment: can u tell me more about it ? or simple JSFidlle  so first how i can be able to select just the period ( start and end) ( select) not the eventClick ???

Comment: on stackoverflow you should show your code first. So, create fiddle and I'll try to help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7djq37x6/1/

Comment: still waiting for you !